# srting to dictionary or json after subprocess check_output

Tags: python, string, dictionary, subprocess

I'm using `subprocess check_output` and I have an outputted string to work with:

```
import subprocess
import sys

command = 'some command'
a = subprocess.check_output(command,shell=True).decode(sys.stdout.encoding)

print(repr(a))
```

i am receiving this string as output.

```
[ { id: 'id_number1',\n    status: 'running'},\n { id: 'id_number2',\n    status: 'running'}]\n
```

String as example, in real string each object has 20+ key , and objects `{.. }`may be 1 or 10

real string for 1 object

```
[ { id: '6b2708c992d1b469f32c9d1143ed9a758a20ef57',\n    status: 'running',\n    configPath: 'D:\\\\Sre\\\\',\n    uptime: '2h 4m 35s',\n    restarts: 0,\n    peers: 172,\n    offers: 417,\n    dataReceivedCount: 6,\n    delta: '-12ms',\n    port: 4232,\n    stor: '25',\n    percent: '1' } ]\n
```

I'd like to convert this string into a Python 3 dictionary or json.

Comment: `from ast import literal_eval` and then `literal_eval(a)` - does that work?

Comment: i tried error `ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x037513D0>`

Comment: can you post a longer output string?

Comment: Add real big string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if it's not so elegant, try:

```
string = "[ { id: 'id_number1',\n    status: 'running'},\n { id: 'id_number2',\n    status: 'running'}]\n"

dict_subproc = {}
listfromstr = string.replace("[", "").replace(" ", "").replace(",", "").replace("[", "").replace("{", "").replace("}", "").replace("]", "").split("\n")

lst =  [j for i in listfromstr for j in i.split(":")]

for i, itm in enumerate(lst):
    if itm == "id":
        dict_subproc[lst[i+1]] = lst[i+3]
```

**EDIT**

List of Dictionary:

```
string = "[ { id: 'id_number1',\n    status: 'running'},\n { id: 'id_number2',\n    status: 'running'}]\n"

list_subproc = []
listfromstr = string.replace("[", "").replace(" ", "").replace(",", "").replace("[", "").replace("{", "").replace("}", "").replace("]", "").split("\n")

lst =  [j for i in listfromstr for j in i.split(":")]

for i, itm in enumerate(lst):
    if itm == "id":
        list_subproc.append({itm : lst[i+1], lst[i+2] : lst[i+3]})
```

Comment: something wrong i received ` {"'id_number'": "'running'"}`  but keys is missung `id` and `status`

Comment: Do you want a list of dictionary `[{id = id1, status=running}, {id = id2, status=running}]` or a dictionary `{id1: running, id2: running}`?

Comment: i need [{u'status': u'running', u'id': u'id_number1'}, {u'status': u'running', u'id': u'id_number2'}]

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to transform your string to a JSON compliant format.

```
import json

s = "[ { id: 'id_number1',\n    status: 'running'},\n { id: 'id_number2',\n    status: 'running'}]\n"

s=s.replace(' ', '')
s=s.replace('\n', '')
s=s.replace('status:', '"status":')
s=s.replace('id:', '"id":')
s=s.replace('\'', '\"')

d = json.loads(s)
print d
```

And it will output :

```
[{u'status': u'running', u'id': u'id_number1'}, {u'status': u'running', u'id': u'id_number2'}]
```

as a python's list of dictionnaries.

Comment: I think that this is too specific, try to write a more general answer

Comment: It's definitively too specific but it's a way to achieve it if the string format is strictly the one provided in the author's post. To write a more generic answer, we need a more generic string format from the author because we can imagine anything we want.

Comment: there are more then 2 keys( i show only in example 2 keys) almost 20+ keys it is not good to use x20 relpace i think

Comment: Definitvely not. You should use a regex to match each key. hint : Each key ends by a `':'`.

Answer (score 0):

this works.

```
a = "[ { id: 'id_number1',\n    status: 'running'},\n { id: 'id_number2',\n    status: 'running'}]\n"


a = a[1:-2].replace("    ", "").split("\n")

listone = ["".join(a[:2]),
           "".join(a[2:])]

lista =[eval(listone[0][:-1].replace("{", "{'").replace(":", "':").replace(",", ",'")),
        eval(listone[1].replace("{", "{'").replace(":", "':").replace(",", ",'"))]
```

output:

```
>>> lista
[{'status': 'running', ' id': 'id_number1'}, {'status': 'running', ' id': 'id_number2'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution, may be it isn't fine but..

```
import re
import subprocess

a = subprocess.check_output(command,shell=True).decode('utf-8')

#using replace to isolate keys and values
new = a.replace('{ ', ';').replace(' }',', }'). replace('\n    ', ';').replace(': ',':@')

findkeys = re.compile(r';(\S*?):')
keys_list = findkeys.findall(new)
findvalue= re.compile(r'@(.*?),')
values_list = findvalue.findall(new)
info = dict(zip(keys_list, values_list))
print(info)
```